# how to dynamically change item of two related combobox

Tags: javascript, php

I have two mySQL tables `tbl1` and `tbl2` `tbl1` has a primary key column who reference in `tbl2` column. Now I have html form in which two combobox is available . I shows all data of `tbl1` into first combobox. Now I want to show the related data of `tbl2` into second combobox after selection of item in first combobox.

So please explain me simple and easy technique to achieve it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: where is your code, what have you tried

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [The How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your show code and any error messages!

Comment: Sorry about that but your answer helps me and i have completed by project. Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In Short:**

1. In `file1.php`, Retrieve mysql `tbl1` and display it in a combo box.
2. On change of Combo box, Fetch the value of option and pass it a php file `file2.php` via ajax and Display the output in `file1.php` which is produced by `file2.php`.
3. In `file2.php`, Retrieve mysql `tbl2` with the Id passed by Ajax and generate a combo box.

**Example:**

**index.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function GetXmlHttpObject()
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        return new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    if (window.ActiveXObject)
    {
        return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }   
    return null;
}

function ajax_function(url, postData, id)
{
    xmlhttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
    xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", postData.length);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4)
        {
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;                            
        }       
    }                
        xmlhttp.send(postData);
}

function dispSecond(Id)
{
    var params  = 'Id=' + Id ;
    var DivId = 'dispDiv';
    ajax_function('ajax_display.php', params, DivId);
}

</script>

<?php
/* Mysqli query to retrieve and store in $ArrayList(Id=>Text)
   Example:  $ArrayList = array(1=>'Ford',2=>'Chevy');
*/
?>

<select id="drop_first" name="drop_first" onchange="return dispSecond(this.value);">
<option value="0">[Select]</option>
<?php
foreach ($ArrayList as $k=>$v)
{
echo '<option value="'.$k.'">'.$v.'</option>';  
}
?>
</select>

<div id="dispDiv"></div>
```

**ajax_display.php**

```
<?php
$Id     = isset($_REQUEST['Id']) ? $_REQUEST['Id'] : '';
if ($Id)
{
/* Mysqli query to retrieve and store in $SubArray where $Id
   Example:  
   If $Id=1 
   $SubArray = array(1=>'Focus',2=>'Explorer');
   If $Id=2
   $SubArray = array(1=>'Cavalier',2=>'Impala', 3=>'Malibu');
*/
?>
    <select id="drop_second" name="drop_second">
    <option value="0">[Select]</option>
    <?php
    foreach ($SubArray as $k=>$v)
    {
    echo '<option value="'.$k.'">'.$v.'</option>';  
    }
    ?>
    </select>
<?php
}
?>
```

**Note:**

Use Mysqli or PDO instead mysql

Below Demo and Download are based on arrays, you can implement by using mysqli retrieval.

Also You can try using $.ajax which is more easy also.

[DEMO](http://webplums.com/temp/demo_23465792/#)  | [DOWNLOAD](http://webplums.com/temp/demo_23465792/demo_23465792.rar)